# To increase the value of i by using "for"?

Tags: python

I want to create a code that outputs characters such as a3b4 like aaabbbb.
In the case of short lines, I can write the code myself, such as i+2, i+4, but I would like to receive input the same value as a3b4 and print out the same value as a2b3c6a2 as abbcccaa.

The code I wrote recognizes only four strings and extracts them.
I think we need to automatically increase the value that i can recognize, but I don't know how to write the code here.
How should I refine?

```
s_list=list(input("Extracting?"))
i=0
def extracting(s_list):
    for i in range(0,len(s_list),2):
        result = s_list[i]*int(s_list[i+1])
        result += s_list[i+2]*int(s_list[i+3])
        return result

a=extracting(s_list)
print(a)
```

Comment: you are always returning on your first iteration, that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are always returning on your firs iteration. Instead, you need to accumulate your final result from each intermediate result in the loop body. So do something like:

```
def extracting(s_list):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,len(s_list),2):
        result.append(s_list[i]*int(s_list[i+1]))
    return ''.join(result)
```

Note also, there is no point, really, in converting your input into `list`, `str` objects are also sequences and support all the necessary operations you are using on your `s_list` here. In any case, here's a cheeky, one-liner, just for fun:

```
>>> s = 'a2b3c6a2'
>>> ''.join([x*i for x, i in zip(s[::2], map(int, s[1::2]))])
'aabbbccccccaa'
```